# When the "loadOp" in VkAttachmentDescription is executed?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm creating an application that renders shadows with a simple shadow map.

Passes are done like this :
offscreen pass creating shadow map -> last pass rendering to swapchain and using the depth texture from the previous pass

My problem is with the first pass. I render a model with a single vertex shader and associate a depth texture only.
In the pipeline I have only one attachment :

```
VkAttachmentDescription depthAttachment = {};
depthAttachment.format = m_depthFormat;
depthAttachment.samples = m_msaaSamples;
depthAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
depthAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
depthAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
depthAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
```

Here I set "loadOp" to VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR but it seems that the operation is done before the second pass execution.
Setting "loadOp" to VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE works on IntelHD Graphics but not on Nvidia graphic card.

I'm not sure when the "loadOp" is executed.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: "*it seems that the operation is done before the second pass execution*" How do you know this? "*Setting "loadOp" to VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE works on IntelHD Graphics*" What do you mean by "works"? Also, what do your validation layers say about your code?

Comment: In the second pass I render the texture in a quad. Setting "loadOp" to VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE draw correctly the texture on IntelHD Graphics but setting to VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR get a black texture. That's why I guess the clear is responsible. Validation layers say nothing

Comment: I don't really understand what you're getting at here. You're saying what happens, and you claim that something is being "drawn correctly" in the "second pass", but you're not explained anything about what those things mean. What's going on in the "first pass"? Are you rendering the object properly? Did you use a clear value? Basically, there's no way to debug your problem without a proper [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your help ! The problem was due to clear values indeed I was using 2 clear values for only 1 attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to clear values.

I was using 2 clear values :

```
std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues = {};
clearValues[0].color = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
clearValues[1].depthStencil = { 1.0f };
```

The correct clear is with only the depth clear :

```
std::array<VkClearValue, 1> clearValues = {};
clearValues[0].depthStencil = { 1.0f };
```